# Select Class not working on drop down menu in Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

This issue seems to be related to Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.88.

Select is not working for the dropdown menu even though, I could click on the element.

html sample:

```html
<select id="Month" class="span span15" tabindex="8" name="Month" size="1">
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
</select>
```

Java code:

```java
@FindBy(xpath = "//select[@id='Month']")
private WebElement dateOfBirthMonth;

public void selectMonth(String mm) {
    Select selectAdults = new Select(dateOfBirthMonth);
    selectAdults.selectByVisibleText(mm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, the problem was due to the wrong test data reference in the excel sheet (used to store the test data). The problem has been rectified and it is now working.